# How to modify width of before/after in media query

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries

I have this code below to create line before and after a text with Sass. I would like to modify the width with a media query. It seems my code doesn’t work but I do not have any idea of what to do.

```
span {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 1rem;
      position: relative;
      color: $grey2;

      &::before {
        content: "   ";
        height: 2px;
        background: $grey1;
        width: 38%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
      }
      &::after {
        content: "";
        height: 2px;
        background: $grey1;
        width: 38%;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
      }
```

I would like to modify the width of my line with media query and I have this. The red background works but not the rest :

```
    span {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 1rem;
      position: relative;
      color: $grey2;

      &::before {
        content: "   ";
        height: 2px;
        background: $grey1;
        width: 38%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
      }
      &::after {
        content: "";
        height: 2px;
        background: $grey1;
        width: 38%;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        background: red;
        span {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          font-size: 1rem;
          position: relative;
          color: $grey2;

          &::before {
            content: "";
            height: 2px;
            background: $grey1;
            width: 10%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
          }
          &::after {
            content: "";
            height: 2px;
            background: $grey1;
            width: 10%;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
          }
        }
      }
```

I would like to modify my before and after span with media query.
Someone has an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: what's exactly wrong? I converted your style as is to vanilla css and it behaves as expected. When you resize the window so that the width is <= 700px, the width of those lines are `10%` as the only thing different from the style outside the media query.

Comment: The first span element isn't closed, a '**}**' is missing, is that intentional ?

Comment: @DiegoD, maybe it was that! Thanks to respond me :).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your media query doesn't work because you put it inside of the span selector and select the span again inside the media query.

Just do that :

```
span {
    //some style

    &::before {
        //some style
    }

    &::after {
        //some style
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        //some new style for your span 

        &::before {
            //some new style
        }

        &::after {
            //some new style
        }
    }
}
```